# Object assignment in C#

Tags: c#, object, variable-assignment

This is something I encountered while using the C# IList collections

```
IList<MyClass> foo = new List<MyClass>();
var bar = new List<MyClass>();

foo.AddRange() // doesn't compile
bar.AddRange() // compile
```

As far as I know, in C# (on the contrary of C++) when we create an object with this syntax, the object type get the right side (assignment) and not the left one (declaration).

Do I miss something here !

`EDIT`

I still don't get it, even after your answers, foo and bar have the same type !
[image]

Comment: "var" is of Type List<MyClass> which has the method "AddRange" whereas foo is of type IList<T> which is an interface that doesn't have the "AddRange" method.

Comment: But both of them get instantiated with the type List<MyClass>

Comment: @Schneider That is true, but from the compiler's point of view, `foo` is of type `IList<>` not `List<>`

Comment: Yes but you cast one variable (foo) implicitly to IList<T>

Comment: The point is that the object you created is of type List, but the _variable you use to refer to it_ isn't.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's nothing so subtle going on here:

- foo has the type `IList<MyClass>` and `IList<T>` doesn't have an AddRange method
- bar has the type `List<MyClass>` and `List<T>` does have an AddRange method.

That's all.  It would be just the same in C++.

Update: In the edited-in addition, you're calling GetType(), which gets the run-time type of the object - at compile time the compiler is looking at the static type of the foo and bar variables.

Thinking about `Object myObj = "MyString"` might make things clearer, because there is a more obvious difference between an 'Object' and a 'String', even though they have the same inheritance relationship as IList and List

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you are using the interface and `IList` does not have `AddRange` but `List` does have `AddRange`

If you change it to

```
List<MyClass> foo = new List<MyClass>();
```

it will work. as it has this method.

Here is what  [`IList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has

You can also do

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> foo = new List<MyClass>();
```

And you will find that this constrains it even more

EDIT FOR YOUR EDIT:

They will both be the same type becuase both are still `Lists`. The difference comes in with the variable that you are using. By using the interface, you are limiting the operations to those that the interface supports. As `List` implements `IList`, `IList` has a subset of the operations that `List` has.

The underlying object is still a `List`.

Answer (score 2):

The underlying type of `foo` is List, but its static type, which the compiler uses to ensure correctness, is `IList<T>`. Anything that you invoke on `foo` must be declared as part of the `IList<T>` type.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
List<MyClass> foo = new List<MyClass>(); // CHANGED TO List<> rather than IList<>
var bar = new List<MyClass>();

foo.AddRange() // doesn't compile
bar.AddRange() // compile
```

Answer (score 0):

Also the IList declares a behavior and not a concrete type. Please see here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

In the a List you can add items and IList type is an already constructed type, which implements this interface.

Answer (score 0):

I have not understood your question, but in this situation C# and C++ act the same way. In your example that to provide that the code would be compiled you could write

```
IList<MyClass> foo = new List<MyClass>();
var bar = new List<MyClass>();

( (List<MyClass> )foo ).AddRange(); 
bar.AddRange() // compile
```

In fact it has the same sense as dynamic_cast in C++.

Answer (score 0):

As the all said IList does not support AddRange and it does not need to support it.

You can:

```
1 ) ((List<MyClass>)foo).AddRange(anotherList);
2 ) You can also use extension method to AddRange
3 ) There are another workarounds for this problem e.g. Concat etc.
```

I think also, the interface shall not support every function on the class at some point you need abstraction and this shall be based on ***interface segregation principle***.